# unable to capture div's style.display value lwc

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, css

I'm trying to capture the display css property value for an element.
However, unless I set style.display value in js it doesn't work.
HTML:

```
<div class ="dropdown slds-size_1-of-4" >
   <p>A</p>
   <p>B</p>
   <p>C</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: white;
}
```

JS: Below JS method is be called from one of the input boxes in html:

```
updateDropDownStyle(){
   console.log('display : '   ,this.template.querySelector('.dropdown').style.display);
}
```

However, the console prints nothing at all. However, if in the same method I set the **element.style.display** value as **none** and then try to console the above - it prints **none**.
What's the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

That's expected. The classes do not impose their values on to the style attribute of DOM element. If you want to know the style, use getComputedStyle instead:

```
let style = window.getComputedStyle(this.template.querySelector('.dropdown'));
console.log(style.display); // should output "none"
```

---

## Demo

```
<template>
<div class="dropdown slds-size_1-of-4" >
   <p>A</p>
   <p>B</p>
   <p>C</p>
</div>
{classValue}

<lightning-button label="Update" onclick={updateDropDownStyle}>
</lightning-button>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    classValue;
    updateDropDownStyle(){
        this.classValue = window.getComputedStyle(
            this.template.querySelector('.dropdown')
        ).display;
    }
}
```